# presto split single column value to multiple rows

Tags: sql, join, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table on presto that has records of multiple records. From that record, I used this simple SQL query,

```
select id, data from my_table where id IN (1,7)
```

This is what I get from that query,

```
id        data
1   ('A', 0.0, 12)
7   ('B', 0.0, 20) ('A', 0.0, 30) ('C', 0.0, 40)
```

Now I want to make this data column multiple rows like below, basically, split single column value into multiple rows.

```
name value age
A    0.0   12
B    0.0   20
A    0.0   30
C    0.0   40
```

What I've tried so far, but getting an error on presto

```
SELECT data
FROM my_table
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(data, ' ') where id IN (1,7);
```

**My idea was** to split the column value with space then make another split by a comma to make multiple columns at the end. Seems I need to utilize the `split()` and `split_part()` from [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html) but I couldn't make it work. Please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: What's the type of the `data` column?

Comment: Its a string type column @MartinTraverso sir

Comment: See `UNNEST` examples at https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest and string splitting functions at https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#split. HTH

Comment: I've tried the below answer but it doesn't work for `('B', 0.0, 20) ('A', 0.0, 30) ('C', 0.0, 40)`, @PiotrFindeisen if you don't mind sir, can you give an answer/example for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `split`, `unnest`, `replace` and `try` I am able to do the query workable now **just wanted to know is there any other way to do/fix it?** because I'm not fully satisfied with this way :)

```
WITH t AS (
select data  from my_table where id IN (1,7)
)

SELECT
  try(trim(data_parts[1])) AS name,
  try(trim(data_parts[2])) AS age,
  try(trim(data_parts[3])) AS value
FROM (
  SELECT split(replace(split_Col2,'('),',') as data_parts 
FROM t
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(data,')')) AS t (split_Col2) 
) WHERE length(try(trim(data_parts[1]))) > 0
```

**Result**

```
     name   age  value
34  'AAAA'  0.0 'NNNNN' 
36  'BBBB'  0.0 'NNNNN'     
38  'CCCC'  0.0 'MMMMM'
39  'AAAA'  0.0 'CCCCC'
```